# Issue converting SQL code to PySpark; Where I am creating a new DF with a groupby and count

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks

I have below sql code which I am trying to convert to PySpark (Code below), any input into best way to convert the sql logic into PySpark would be much appreciated;

**SQL Code:**
%sql

```
drop table if exists jrny_map_web_sum;
create table jrny_map_web_sum as select mid_key, completedt, interaction_dt, interaction_type, count(distinct(visit_identifier)) as visits, count(*) as pvs
from web_drvsjoin1
group by mid_key, completedt, interaction_dt, interaction_type;
```

Sample O/P:
[image]

**PySpark Code:**

```
jrny_map_web_sum1 = web_drvsjoin1.select("mid_key","completedt", "interaction_dt", "interaction_type", "visit_identifier").groupBy("mid_key", "completedt", "interaction_dt", "interaction_type").agg(countDistinct("visit_identifier").alias("Visits"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

jrny_map_web_sum1 = web_drvsjoin1.\
select("mid_key","completedt", "interaction_dt", "interaction_type", "visit_identifier").\
groupBy("mid_key", "completedt", "interaction_dt", "interaction_type").\
agg(countDistinct(col("visit_identifier")).alias("visits"),count("*").alias("pvs"))

#saving dataframe as table
jrny_map_web_sum1.saveAsTable("<db>.jrny_map_web_sum")
```